# Pandas regex to remove digits before consecutive dots

Tags: python, regex

I have a string `Node57Name123.grpObject12.grp23Symbol43.shape52.anotherobject25.shape23`.

1. Removing all the numbers that are before the dot and after the word.
2. Ignoring the first part of the string i.e. `"Node57Name123"`.
3. Should not remove the digits if they are inside words.

Tried `re.sub(r"\d+","",string)` but it removed every other digit.

The output should look like this `"Node57Name123.grpObject.grp23Symbol.shape.anotherobject.shape"`

Can you please point me to the right direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
re.sub(r'^([^.]*\.)|\d+(?![^.])', r'\1', text)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/1HnNoZ/1/).

*Details*:

- `^([^.]*\.)` - zero or more chars other than a dot and then a `.` char at the start of the string captured into Group 1 (referred to with `\1` from the replacement pattern)
- `|` - or
- `\d+(?![^.])` - one or more digits followed with a dot or end of string (=`(?=\.|$)`).

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/YBXRmv):

```
import re
text = r'Node57Name123.grpObject12.grp23Symbol43.shape52.anotherobject25.shape23'
print( re.sub(r'^([^.]*\.)|\d+(?![^.])', r'\1', text) )
## => Node57Name123.grpObject.grp23Symbol.shape.anotherobject.shape
```

Comment: OMG, you are a savior, Not even few minutes and you answered it.
On a personal note, can you please point me to a guide to understand regex better?

Comment: @PratikV I [wrote a post about it](https://www.buymeacoffee.com/wstribizew/my-regex-road-so-far) since a lot of people ask me the same.

Answer (score 1):

Just to give you a non-regex alternative' using [`rstrip()`](https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/str/rstrip.html). We can feed this function a bunch of characters to remove from the right of the string e.g.: `rstrip('0123456789')`. Alternatively we can also use the ***digits*** constant from the [`string`](https://www.journaldev.com/23788/python-string-module) module:

```
from string import digits
s = 'Node57Name123.grpObject12.grp23Symbol43.shape52.anotherobject25.shape23'
x = '.'.join([s.split('.')[0]] + [i.rstrip(digits) for i in s.split('.')[1:]])
print(x)
```

Prints:

```
Node57Name123.grpObject.grp23Symbol.shape.anotherobject.shape
```

---

**EDIT:**

If you must use a regular pattern, it seems that the following covers your sample:

```
(\.[^.]*?)\d+\b
```

Replace with the 1st capture group, see the online [demo](https://regex101.com/r/394MBc/1)

- `(` - Open capture group:

  - `\.[^.]*?` - A literal dot followed by 0+ non-dot characters (lazy).
  - `)` - Close capture group.
- `\d+\b` - Match 1+ digits up to a word-boundary.

A sample:

```
import re
s = 'Node57Name123.grpObject12.grp23Symbol43.shape52.anotherobject25.shape23'
x = re.sub(r'(\.[^.]*?)\d+\b', r'\1', s)
print(x)
```

Prints:

```
Node57Name123.grpObject.grp23Symbol.shape.anotherobject.shape
```